# Wordpress Filter Buttons: Content fading out and fading in

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am using this javascript to turn on and off the display of certain content on a website, depending on the contents category set in the backend:

```
<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(600);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).hide();
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

When the content which is being set to `active` (i.e. is being displayed) it fades in nicely. How can I let the disappearing content fade out just as smoothly? As of right now it merely disappears instantly, which heavily breaks with the visual feel of the website.

A live demo of the script can be seen here: http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/projekte/

Comment: Do you have a live demo?

Comment: Why not just $('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut(600); instead of hide();

Comment: Jap, the script is being used on this web project I am working on: http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/projekte/

The buttons are at the top, below the main menu ("alle" "WiSe 15/16" and so on). The website is in German, apologies for that, but the function of the buttons as well as my current fading.in/fading-out problem should be apparent nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried fadeOut();?

```
<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(600);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut(600);
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: perfectly does the trick, thanks so much. I'm very, very new to javascript and didn't know that I can actually add the fadeOut just the same way the fadeIn is done

Comment: hide() method sets the display property to none, which is not animatable. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp . fadeOut() however, sets firstly the opacity to 0 before changing the display to none. See http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery method - fadeOut() or define css transitions for the element class.

```
$('.projekte > .post').not($el).hide();
```

Can be replaced with

```
$('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut();
```